# Saving Data to Registry on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, registry, application-variables

I heard that Windows 7 restricts access to its registry, so that applications cannot write directly to it.  Is this so?  I am developing an application in C#, and I would like to be able to save things such as port settings, last file used, etc. between sessions.  Is the registry still a good option, or is there another preferred means of doing this now?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to the registry has been restricted since (at least) Windows NT 4. That does not mean that you cannot write to it; it just means that you cannot write to it *everywhere*. Normally, writing in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` should still be possible.

The registry is still a good option for storing settings. However, you can also save yourself some work and use "[application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)" instead, which are stored in an XML file in the user's profile folder. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600161/why-arent-net-application-settings-stored-in-the-registry) I asked what their advantage was over the registry, resulting in a great discussion of the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas!  I went with the application settings.  They were pretty easy to implement.